# Meaning of the phrasal verb "cut in" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I came across the following usage of *cut in* in the 6th episode of the 2nd season of "Narcos: Mexico":

> If we can weaken Felix without having to go back and **cut in** State, then I can live with there being things I don't know.

None of the definitions that online English dictionaries give seems fit. Would you tell me what it means?

Comment: Who is speaking? Who is "we"?  Was this a translation? Is the original in Spanish or not? To cut someone in means to allow someone to participate in something, often involving money but not here. Here, probably to get credit for getting the bad guys. But I would need to know the speaker and have not seen this series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common enough phrase that most dictionaries will give you [the meaning](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cut-in).

Since the verb is transitive, taking the object "State", we know that the correct meaning in the link above is number 4:

> to allow to have a share

"State" here is the name of an organization, for example "The State Department" in the US. The speaker does not want "State" to have a share in what they are doing.